# Datagridview formatting databound items

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hi is it possible to format a property once it is binded in the datagridview but retain it's original value?

Example I have this item:

```
IList<User> a = new List<User>()
{
    new User { ID = 0, LinkCode = "ABC DEF G" },
    new User { ID = 1  LinkCode = "HIJ KLM N" },
    new User { ID = 2  LinkCode = "ABC DEF G" },
};
```

Then I have a datagridview with two columns that represent the two properties on user collection named "ID" and "LinkCode".

Is it possible to bind the collection but instead of showing the complete "LinkCode" it will just show a Substring of it but retaining the original value in case I want to save it back to the database, it's like the logic of "ValueMember" and "DisplayMember" where "ABC DEF G" is the value member but only "G" will be the display member.

Comment: Create a read only property that returns the substring of "LinkCode"?

Comment: thank you @Abhinav, like what I've told Robban this User object is a POCO generated by entity framework

Comment: Try dataGridView.DataSource=YourListName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to the `User` object that returns just a substring of LinkCode

Something like:

```
public string FormattedLinkCode { get { return LinkCode.Last().ToString(); } }
```

**EDIT:**
To add this functionality to a POCO object created by Entity Framework you could put this property in a partial class. Simply add a partial class to the same namespace in which your POCO resides.

```
public partial class User { 
    public string FormattedLinkCode 
     { 
        get { 
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(LinkCode))
                     return string.Empty;
                return LinkCode.Last().ToString(); 
            } 
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you @Robban but this User object is a POCO generated by entity framework.

Comment: You could still do this, the POCOs generated by entity framework are partial. I'll clarify my example.

Comment: is this an acceptable solution @Robban, I mean in a medium scale project, is this standard? I'm kinda thinking about this as my last resort.

Comment: I would say this is the best way to achieve what you want. It's simple and it's understandable. I can see no disadvantage with this approach and this is the way I always try to solve things if applicable. The FormattedLinkCode is a natural part of the User object and it does not have any dependency on anything else. It belongs there and could henceforth be used everywhere that you want to use the FormattedLinkCode instead of the full LinkCode.

Comment: No problem. Remember to add some null checks to the property as well. if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(LinkCode)) return ""; or something.